# Background color of Dropdown menu is out of the box, how can I solve it?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I am trying to give some style to a dropdown menu, I changed the color but I can see that the color is outside the box like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6kEy.png)

```
     `   dcc.Dropdown(id="select_country",
             options= [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.index],
             multi=False,
             value='World',
             style={'width': "200px",'marginLeft': '1%', 'background-color':'#60d7f7'}
             )`
```

Is there something I could do to fix that? Thanks guys!